# Onclick function not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
function get() {

    $.post(
        'postchatfame.php', 
        {
            comment: postchatfamemsg.comment.value,
            userid: postchatfamemsg.userid.value
        },
        function(output) {
            $('#walls').html(output).show();
        }
    );

    document.forms["postchatfamemsg"].reset();

}
```

This is my code I used as Ajax, to store information into DATABASE. and returned some information in tabular form to the same page without refreshing page.
I called this function `onclick` of button by writing this code.

```
<input name="a" type="button" value="Share" onClick="get();"/>
```

Comment: Get in the habit of being very specific instead of saying "not working". What, exactly, is not working? I can see several possible things here that would not work, but of course I can't see all of your code.

Comment: What so specific? I think firefox is a good for development. But why multi standards. same code is working on all other browsers except firefox only. Mozilla need to follow standards.

Comment: You need to tell us what's not working, and if it works in some browsers: which ones? There's not enough detail here to help, your question is in danger of being closed. Please edit with more information. Example: Does the function get called? Do the values get sent to postchatfame.php? Does this all work but the form doesn't reset? etc.

Comment: my friend, you don't understand.  Firefox typically does follow the standards.  For years they were the leaders.  If we *really* want to talk standards, see http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/ You shouldn't be using `onclick`.

Comment: Function is not called from only and if only I use Firefox. Other browsers like Opera, Chrome, IE, Safari don't have any problem with this onclick function. I use another button in php and which is perfectly fine and work exectly according to my project requirement in firefox. but if and only if i use it in Form and having call above mentioned method, it is not working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a different name for the function - some names already have a meaning in HTML and the DOM, so using such a name may conflict with them (calling a function `submit` has similar problems).

Why not give it a more descriptive name - `getChatFame`, for example?

Comment: I cahnged it now, but it still not working. I also add button on same page, which is calling another method onclick. It is working fine.

Comment: What is not working? Exactly? Errors on the javascript console?

Comment: postchatfamemsg is not defined

Comment: @zeeshan Then the function *is* getting called, but the global variable `postchatfamemsg` *was never assigned a value* so `postchatfamemsg.comment` throws an exception. Lots of time could have been saved by adding more error descriptions in the post ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Because Fx uses standards

comment: postchatfamemsg.comment.value,
will not work on its own. It will work in IE for example because IE overloads the scope with all possible things, which is also why document.getElementById('formname') will work in IE and not in Fx

Use `comment: document.forms["postchatfamemsg"].comment.value,`

Complete code

```
function sedData() { // get is a poor function name, especially when you post
    var form = document.forms["postchatfamemsg"];
    $.post(
        'postchatfame.php', 
        {
            comment: form.comment.value,
            userid: form.userid.value
        },
        function(output) {
            $('#walls').html(output).show();
        }
    );

    form.reset();

}
```

Comment: +1 Haha. Impressive deduction.

Comment: thanx bro. I love stackoverflow team. thanks every one.

Answer (score 0):

**Ask yourself:**

- Did you define your function physically in code before trying to use it?
- Is `jQuery` or whatever library you are using loaded before you try to use `$.ajax`?
- Do you have errors in the JavaScript console?
- Can you verify that any part of the process worked in the troublesome browser?

Comment: yes bro i assure all things. you are mentioning. can you please give me solved example. which is working on firefox

Comment: Reread: **Can you verify that any part of the process worked in the troublesome browser?**  Does ANY part of your code work in Firefox?  Does `get()` actually get called?  Does the ajax response come back?

Comment: that is exactly the problem thanks. Actually function is not called perfectly. Here is message in console that postchatfamemsg is not defined. but i defined it. it is a form name.